# How to bind Logged in user automatically in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I want to automatically bind current user object to the **Project** object when a **Project** is created.

Model:

```
public class Project
{
   public string ProjectId { get; set; }

   public string UserId { get; set; }

   public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProjectId,UserId")] Project project)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      _context.Add(project);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
  }

   return View(project);
}
```

I have searched the internet but couldn't find a satisfying answer yet.
Thank You!

Comment: The `Bind` attribute is for model binding from a request so is the `UserId` being submitted but not binded? or you want to bind to the current logged in user ?

Comment: Do you mean that before adding project, get the id of the currently logged in user, bind the id value to the project's `UserId`  or `User` ,and then save project to the database ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to automatically bind current user object to the Project object when a Project is created.

Based on your code, it seems that you implement relationship between `Project` and `ApplicationUser`, and `Project.UserId` is the foreign key.

To achieve your requirement, you can refer to the following code snippet to dynamically populate `UserId` input based on current signed-in user.

```
@model Project
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Project</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserId" readonly class="form-control" value="@UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Id" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test Result

[image]